# How does an executable within a gem reference the greater gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Say that my gem is *VideoPlayer*. The folders tructure is:

```
VideoPlayer/
    /bin
        vidplay.rb
    /lib
        VideoPlayer.rb
        Subtitler.rb
        Screenshotter.rb
```

I want people to invoke `vidplay` from the command line, and for `vidplay` to reference code in the `VideoPlayer`, `Subtitler` and `Screenshotter` files.

If I just write, within `vidplay.rb`, `require '../lib/VideoPlayer.rb'`, it will throw an error, saying that it cannot require such file. I thought "Maybe it automatically requires everything in `lib/`", but it apparently doesn't; if I don't require *anything*, it'll say that VideoPlayer is an uninitialised constant.

So how does this work?

Comment: Could you add your `gemspec` file?

Comment: @GabrieldeOliveira In my GemSpec is `spec.executables = spec.files.grep(%r(^bin/}) {|f| File.basename(f)}` (which was automatically added by my IDE) and the line I've added, `spec.executables << 'vidplay.rb'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually add the `lib` dir to the library load path (`$:`). You can add this to the top of your bin file.

```
lib = File.expand_path('../../lib', __FILE__)
$:.unshift(lib) unless $:.include?(lib)
```

Then you can do a normal require:

```
require 'videoplayer'
```

Hope this helps.